# Is it insecure to send a request to reset token to previous state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, web, meteor

I am using Meteor and its account system. My enrollment process involves a few steps on resetting the password.

```
Template['enrollment'].events({
  'submit #reset-password-form': function (e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let token = Session.get('_resetPasswordToken');
    let user = Meteor.users.findOne({ "services.password.reset.token": token });
    let password = $(e.target).find('input#password').val();

    if (AutoForm.validateForm('reset-password-form')) {
      resetPasswordAsync(token, password)
        .then(() => {
          return Meteor.promise('Orders.initialize', template.data);
        })
        // a few more `.then()s`
        .catch((error) => {
          Notify.warn(error.message);
          Meteor.call('User._resetToken', user, token);
        })
    }
  }
});
```

The reason for this is because if anything fails in the promise chain, then they will remain on the same page but have an "uninitialized" state.

I use a meteor method, because a user should not be able to change his/her services to change their token back.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'User._resetToken': function (user, token) {
    check(user, Meteor.users.simpleSchema());
    check(token, String);
    Meteor.users.update(user._id, {
      "services.password.reset.token": token
    });
  }
});
```

I vaguely feel like this is insecure, but can't quite tell why. Is there any exploits where resetting the user token on a callback can be exploited?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly don't provide the user object to the method, a user might be able to reset *a different user's* reset token.

Secondly, just because you've put it in a server method doesn't make it secure. A user from the console can type `Meteor.call(user,token)` and reset their token or any other user's token (assuming they know the other user's *_id*.

If the user has already reset their password the token is no longer necessary at all. It only needs to lead a short life.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point, I can use `this.userId` on the server because they will technically be logged in, thank you!

Comment: I just blogged about this very issue today http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/07/meteor-security-no-1-meteorcall.html